# Mapping node is not showing texture

Tags: texturing, materials, vector-mapping

I have a floor texture added to my material as a color. I would like to repeat the texture, make the initial texture smaller.
I know I can do that by adding a Mapping Node and adding the vector to the input vector of the Texture Node. But when I attach the Mapping Node I stop seeing the texture correctly. It looks like it just scales up the texture way bigger than it should be, but when I try to scale it down (or up), I never see the texture come back. I only see different shades of the colors also appearing in the texture. Whatever parameter I change in the Mapping Node, I keep seeing shades, but never the actual texture. When I remove the Mapping Node I see the texture correctly again, so there's nothing wrong with my viewport.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hey :). You also need to add a *Texture Coordinate node > UV* before the mapping node.

Comment: Thanks! This does indeed work. :) Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I should also add a Texture Coordinate Node and attach it to the Mapping Node. That makes the texture visible.